# XML: Extract the Direct Child Tag using BASH Script

Tags: xml, bash

I am writing a BASH script to automate a task. But I am stuck with this problem, trying to get the `<version>` tag value which is a direct child to `<project>` tag

The XML file looks like this,

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
  </parent>
 
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-module</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</project>
```

I want the `<version>` tag which is the direct child to `<project>` tag (in this case with value 1.2)

My current code is,

```
versions=($(grep -oP '(?<=<version>)[^<]+' "../../platform/pom.xml"))
echo ${versions[1]}
```

in which I get all the `<version>` tags and then select the 2nd one. But that's not the correct way. Correct way is to select the Direct Child `<version>` tag to the `<project>` tag.

Comment: You're dealing with an xml file, so the correct way to approach it is to use an xml parser with xpath support; something like xidel or xmlstarlet, if you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use grep or awk to extract values from an XML file. If you have xpath installed on your system, issue:

```
xpath -q -e "/project/version/text()" file.xml
```

This will extract only the value of the text node under the node `version` which is a direct descendant of `project`.

If xmlstarlet is installed, run:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/project/version" -v "text()" -n file.xml
```

The command xmllint can also be used to get the same result:

```
xmllint --xpath "/project/version/text()" file.xml
```

Comment: It is possible that you have another xpath program installed. Try the xmlstarlet or the xmllint (see edit) solution.

Answer (score 0):

If [ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html) is available/acceptable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ed -s file.xml <<-'EOF'
  /<project>/;/<\/project>/v/version/d
  ,s/^[[:blank:]]*<version>\([^<]\{1,\}\).*$/\1/
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```